# Java Android - Aide Error : There is no applicable contructor to '()'

Tags: java, android

I got a error

> There is no applicable contructor to "()"

in AIDE ,

Here is my code, i think there is no error, but i got the error, how to fix it?

```
   public class ToggleRD extends RadioButton {
    // Implement necessary constructors

    @Override
    public void toggle() {
        if(isChecked()) {
            if(getParent() instanceof RadioGroup) {
                ((RadioGroup)getParent()).clearCheck();
            }
        } else {
            setChecked(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At which line getting error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the docs for [RadioButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioButton.html) you see it offers 4 constructors, but none are without arguments.
The way I got about extending `View` in android is by creating a `private` method (call it `sharedConstructor` or whatever) and call that in each of the constructors. So do it like this:

```
public class ToggleRD extends RadioButton {
    // Implement necessary constructors

    public ToggleRD(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public ToggleRD(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    public ToggleRD(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void toggle() {
        if(isChecked()) {
            if(getParent() instanceof RadioGroup) {
                ((RadioGroup)getParent()).clearCheck();
            }
        } else {
            setChecked(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Since you don't override the constructor just go ahead and call `super`.

Comment: It Got Error Expected ' ToggleRD '

Comment: I wrote the answer in a hurry, didn't catch those mistakes. You can try it now.

Comment: HOA ! Thanks you alot :D :D :D :) :) (y)

Answer (score 0):

Try to override it's constructor.

```
RadioButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the default constructors so that Android can create the view out of XML files and recreate Views during usage.

Take a look at these constructors:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

simply call super with the same arguments and your problem should be solved.